# Буква же/жэ в русском

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Буква же/жэ в русском.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Надо посмотреть в словарях**

**Большой толковый словарь**: **ЖЭ**, неизм.; ж. и ср. Название буквы "ж".

**Википедия**: Ж, ж (название: **же, жэ**) — буква всех славянских кириллических алфавитов (восьмая в русском[1], белорусском, сербском и македонском, седьмая в болгарском и девятая в украинском).

В орфографическом словаре **информации нет**.

2. **Выбираем по правилу? А по какому?**

Пользователи в Интернете тоже думают:

Вообще подразумевается **ЖЕ и ШЕ**, потому что Ж и Ш обозначают всегда **твердые звуки.**
В иноязычных словах может писаться и ЖЭ и ШЭ.  Редкие случаи употребления данных буквосочетаний есть, но для русского языка они не характерны.

**Косвенным правилом** на сей счёт служит восьмой параграф **Правил-56:** § 8. Буква э пишется только в следующих русских словах: этот, этакий, этак, экий, эк, эй, эх, эхма, эва, эге. "
Отсюда следует, что в любом другом русском слове (именно исконно русском) буквы Э быть не должно.

**ПАС  § 25.** Буква э пишется после букв ж, ч, ш, ц только в следующих особых случаях: 1. В аббревиатурах, напр.: ЖЭК. 2. После приставки меж-, первых частей сложных и сложносокращенных слов в начале корней, начинающихся с буквы э, напр.: межэтажный.
3. При передаче некоторых китайских слов, напр.: шэ (народность в Китае).

Тоже **нет однозначного ответа...**

**3. Графика русского письма?**

**Бука Э** в русском языке после согласных пишется **в ограниченном количестве слов,** причем это касается всегда твердых Ж и Ш в исконно русских словах. Однако **исключения** возможны...

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

```
 — Как же записать название буквы?  А, понятное дело!  
 Выбираем ЖЭ, как в толковом словаре. 

 — Но почему?! 

 — Нам ЖЕ надо  отличать букву ЖЭ от частицы ЖЕ))
```